# Interpolation of a set of points that include a non-numeric real constants

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, interpolation, data

I have a set of data like:

```
matrix=Table[{x,y,x+y*c1},{x,0,1,0.1},{y,0,1,0.1}]
```

where 'c1' is a real constant.
I'm trying to create an interpolation function called 'fun' like:

```
fun=Interpolation[matrix,Method->"Spline"]
```

It obviously creates a little problem beacuse 'c1' has not a numeric values.
My question: is it possible to create an interpolation function with a non-numeric constant, like 'c1' in the previously case?

Thanks for any tips and helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) data needs to be structured as `{{x1, y1}, f1}, {x2, y2}, f2}, ...}`

```
data = Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, x + y*c1}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}], 1];

f[c1_] = Interpolation[data]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[f[c1][x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}],
 {{c1, 1}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]